# Can't get "Gluon Glisten" dependency library in Eclipse's Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq/charm-glisten/5.0.2
I want to use Gluon\AutoCompleteTextField, but I can't get this dependency library in Eclipse's Maven. What's the problem? (Jdk11, JavaFX11)

Comment: *can't get this dependency library in Eclipse's Maven*... describe what you see and why do you think so and maybe people could help you better.

Comment: This error is displayed in pom.xml "Missing artifact com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:jar:5.0.2", my other libraries are fine, I think this library may have been removed from Maven.

Comment: The library is part of Gluon Mobile, intended for mobile applications (that run on desktop as well). It requires commercial license and it is not ready for Java 11 yet.

Answer (score 1):

update your pom with

```
<project>
...
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>charm-glisten</id>
    <name>charm-glisten Repository</name>
    <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...
</project>
```

the problem already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730541/the-pom-for-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available-even-though-it?rq=1)