# Maven says POM for dependency is missing despite it being included

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am attempting to use the library [smartcar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.smartcar.sdk/java-sdk/2.0.6). When I deploy/run my application, I receive the following error: `[WARNING] The POM for com.smartcar.sdk:java-sdk:jar:2.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available`. However, upon looking in the [files](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/smartcar/sdk/java-sdk/2.0.6/) included, I see a pom is included. When I download it, the group ID and artifact ID are correct.

What is causing the warning and thus my inability to use the dependency?

Comment: Do you use repositories in your pom file or have you configured repositories in your settings.xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The POM for … is missing, no dependency information available” even though it exists in Maven Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730541/the-pom-for-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available-even-though-it)