# Maven dependecy:go-offline doesn't download transitive dependencies

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven

**I want** to add a separate dependency layer to my dockerfile.

**I'm running** `mvn dependencies:go-offline` but after that `mvn install -o` reports that not all deps are found. After inspecting the error message it turned out that no transitive dependencies were downloading. The issue was fixed by explicitly defining all missing packages in `pom.xml`, but obviously it's not ideal.

This is my dockerfile

```
// copy pom.xml

RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

// copy source code

RUN ./mvnw install -o
```

Is there an alternative to `dependency:go-offline`, or a flag for that command, that will **download all dependencies** needed to run `install -o`, not just direct ones?

**UPD:**
This are the missing dependencies

```
[WARNING] The POM for javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.48 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: It's supposed to do that anyway. ["*resolves all project dependencies, ... **and their dependencies***"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html)

Comment: use `./mvnw dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:go-offline` which should include all plugins needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum It downloaded a lot more stuff but still the same missing dependencies

Comment: @M.Deinum go-offline already does that. "resolves all project dependencies, **including plugins**"

Comment: No it doesn't and is an known issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well the documentation says it does.

Comment: Which is why it is an issue... Also you shouldn't use `./mvnw install -o` but rather something like `./mvw verify -o` as you don't want to install the dependency in your local repository (that doesn't really make sense).

Comment: Another thing is could you add your `pom.xml` and full `Dockerfile` as  your results might vary depending on the version of Maven and the dependency plugin being used.

Comment: For a more in depth analysis of what works or not see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82).

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments on [issue discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82) there were some improvements related to dependency resolution and fetching in newer versions of `maven-dependency-plugin` (starting with 3.0.0). However by default maven uses version 2.8 of dependency plugin. So in order to use recent versions specify version explicitly:

```
// copy pom.xml

RUN ./mvnw org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.5.0:go-offline

// copy source code

RUN ./mvnw install -o
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. For some reason, `dependency:go-offline` doesn't add pom files to the local repository.

Instead, use `mvn verify` followed by `mvn package`:

```
// copy pom.xml
RUN ./mvnw verify --fail-never

// copy source code
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests -o
```

Check out a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45975194/20085654).